# Transportation problem to minimize the cost using genetic algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, genetic-algorithm

I am new to Genetic Algorithm and Here is a simple part of what i am working on

There are factories (1,2,3) and they can server any of the following customers(ABC) and the transportation costs are given in the table below. There are some fixed cost for A,B,C (2,4,1)

```
     A   B   C
1    5   2   3
2    2   4   6
3    8   5   5
```

How to solve the transportation problem to minimize the cost using a genetic algorithm

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should understand what is a genetic algorithm and why we call it like that. Because we act like a single cell organism and making cross overs and mutations to reach a better state.

So, you need to implement your chromosome first. In your situation, let's take a side, customers or factories. Let's take customers. Your solution will look like

1 -> A

2 -> B

3 -> C

So, your example chromosome is `"ABC"`. Then create another chromosome ("BCA" for example)
Now you need a fitting function which you wish to minimize/maximize. 
This function will calculate your chromosomes' breeding chance. In your situation, that'll be the total cost.
Write a function that calculates the cost for given factory and given customer.

Now, what you're going to do is,

- Pick 2 chromosomes weighted randomly. (Weights are calculated by fitting function)
- Pick an index from 2 chromosomes and create new chromosomes via using their switched parts.
- If new chromosomes have invalid parts (Such as `"ABA"` in your situation), make a fixing move (Make one of "A"s, "C" for example). We call it a "mutation".
- Add your new chromosome to the chromosome set if it wasn't there before.
- Go to first process again.

You'll do this for some iterations. You may have thousands of chromosomes. When you think "it's enough", stop the process and sort the chromosome set ascending/descending. First chromosome will be your result.

I'm aware that makes the process time/chromosome dependent. I'm aware you may or may not find an optimum (fittest according to biology) chromosome if you do not run it enough. But that's called genetic algorithm. Even your first run and second run may or may not produce the same results and that's fine.

Just for your situation, possible chromosome set is very small, so I guarantee that you will find an optimum in a second or two. Because the entire chromosome set is `["ABC", "BCA", "CAB", "BAC", "CBA", "ACB"]` for you.

In summary, you need 3 informations for applying a genetic algorithm:

- How should my chromosome be? (And initial chromosome set)
- What is my fitting function?
- How to make cross-overs in my chromosomes?

There are some other things to care about this problem:

- Without mutation, genetical algorithm can stuck to a local optimum. It still can be used for optimization problems with constraints.
- Even if a chromosome exists with a very low chance to be picked for cross-over, you shouldn't sort and truncate the chromosome set till the end of iterations. Otherwise, you may stuck at a local extremum or worse, you may get an ordinary solution candidate instead of global optimum.
- To fasten your process, pick non-similar initial chromosomes. Without enough mutation rate, finding global optimum could be a real pain.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in nejdetckenobi's answer, in this case the solution search space is too small, i.e. only 8 feasible solutions `["ABC", "BCA", "CAB", "BAC", "CBA", "ACB"]`. I assume this is only a simplified version of your problem, and your problem actually contains more factories and customers (but the numbers of factories and customers are equal). In this case, you can just make use of special mutation and crossover to avoid infeasible solution with repeating customers, e.g. `["ABA", 'CCB', etc.]`.

For mutation, I suggest to use a swap mutation, i.e. randomly pick two customers, swap their corresponding factory (position):

A**BC** mutate to  A**CB**

**A**B**C** mutate to **C**B**A**